# Django with Apache working for admin page but gives 404 for all other urls

Tags: python, django, apache

I am a django beginner.

I tried to deploy my django(1.10) site from local server using apache2 (2.4.7)
Port opened.

Admin page is getting opened properly but all other views are not getting opened.

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^treedump/',include('treedump.urls')),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/treedump/', permanent=True)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
 ]
```

**TREEDUMP.URLS**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'printx$',views.printx,name = 'printx'),
    url(r'download$',views.download,name = 'download'),

    ]
```

**.CONF FILE IN APACHE**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName *********
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

  Alias /static /data1/ekmmsc/webapp/ekmmsc/static

  WSGIDaemonProcess ekmmsc python-path=/data1/ekmmsc/webapp/ekmmsc python-     home=/data1/ekmmsc/webapp/ekmmsc/ekmmscenv
  WSGIProcessGroup ekmmsc
  WSGIScriptAlias /ekmmsc /data1/ekmmsc/webapp/ekmmsc/ekmmsc/wsgi.py

  # Other directives here ...
  <Directory "/var/www/html/">
    allow from all
    order allow,deny
    AllowOverride All
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/javascript .js
  </Directory>


  <Directory "/data1/ekmmsc/webapp/ekmmsc/static">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/data1/ekmmsc/webapp/ekmmsc/ekmmsc">
    <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>



  </VirtualHost>
```

**OUTPUT**

Not Found

The requested URL /treedump/ was not found on this server.

Any help will be appreciated , i have been working almost for 2 days on this.
Please help.

Comment: What do you have in treedump.urls?

Comment: Hello Daniel, Please find the update treedump.urls file.

Comment: You've hosted your site under /ekmmsc, so you would need to go to /ekmmsc/treedump/. If you used Django's URL generation facilities this would happen automatically.

Comment: Daniel, then how to redirect it to that particular url , because i want to host it inside ekmmsc i.e, i want /ekmmsc redirection to /ekmmsc/treedump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pattern_name` rather than `url` in your view. This will make Django look up the URL by name, rather than using a hard-coded value, so it will take into account the script prefix.

```
RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='index', permanent=True)),
```

Comment: Daniel, Can i add a default like xxx/ekmmsc/ for every url , because django alias is given /ekmmsc in apache conf. so if i am redirecting it is going without ekmmsc and 404 error is coming.
So can you please suggest how to add this default tag for every url regex.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you use the code I have provided, Django will automatically add the prefix.

Comment: Thanks daniel, but now im getting this error:
OSError at /treedump/
Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.7-py2.7.egg/django/utils/_os.py in abspathu, line 31....Please help

Comment: That appears to be a separate issue. Please ask a new question and show the code of the treedump view.